# Storing freshly created database credentials

Tags: php

I'm creating a php application which creates a new database for each new registered user.
How can I secure store the database credentials so it can be retrieved at user login.

- A core database with encrypted database credentials?
- Writing a file outside webroot? What about writing permissions?

Comment: are you really creating a new database for each new user? As in; a new (my)SQL database?! Don't you mean, a new database _record_?

Comment: A new database per user? Since you give no use case, I'll just point out that this is typically bad form. But maybe you know what you're doing...

Comment: Yes a new database per user, we developed an offline software app which connects to a pgsql db, now I'm creating an online interface with the same functionality

Comment: Why do you do that instead of inserting more rows in a table?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to create a "global" database to store the crendentials and the relations to the new databases.

Comment: So each time I need to connect to the customers DB I have to create a connection to the global database ( maybe on a different database server ) to read the credentials / decrypt them and connect to the customers DB?